# Firebase изменяет значение которое я вставляю

Tags: python, firebase, discord.py

Я пытаюсь хранить в Firebase Realtime Database значения для discord бота

```
(ID_СЕРЕРА: ID_КАНАЛА).
```

Но когда я пытаюсь вставить значение 879745042225447012, он изменяет его на 879745042225447000. Я не понимаю в чем проблема.

Вот видео: https://youtu.be/r450zrTeP00

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой тип данных у поля и сколько там разрядов? Там похоже в поле число с плавающей точкой и разрядов на последние цифры тупо не хватает. Либо возьмите тип с подходящей разрядностью (лучше целый), либо храните как строку.

Comment: Например, хотя не совсем что у вас, но последние разряды уже портятся: `int(float(879745042225447012))` даёт `879745042225447040`